# Is there a faster way to save 2d numpy arrays to png

Tags: python, numpy, png

Hi I'm new to python and I'm trying to save a 2d numpy array to a png file.

Each element in my 2d numpy array is an integer between 0 ~ 100, and I have a `getColor()` function to map it into rgb values. The way I'm doing right now is constructing a 3 channel numpy array with the same shape as my 2d numpy array, and map each values to the corresponding rgb values. However, this is taking a lot of time and I feel like there should be a much more efficient way to do so. My code is currently taking about 5 seconds to process one image.

```py
import numpy as np
import imageio

flt_m = get2dArray() # returns a (880*880) numpy array

def getColor(value):
    if(value < 0):
        return (0,0,0)
    elif(value < 50):
        return (100,150,200)
    else:
        return (255,255,255)

canvas = np.zeros((flt_m.shape[0], flt_m.shape[1], 3)).astype(np.uint8)
for row in range(flt_m.shape[0]):
    for col in range(flt_m.shape[1]):
        rgb = getColor(flt_m[row, col])
        for i in range(3):
            canvas[row, col, i] = rgb[i]

imageio.imwrite('test.png', canvas) # saves file to png
```

Comment: Your question says your values range from 0..100, but your code tests for negative values?

Comment: did you try `canvas[row, col] = rgb` ? Module `pillow` can also convert numpy.array  to image - [Image.fromarray](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray) and maybe it will work faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing on numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to set different subsets of an array.

So perhaps you use:

```
canvas = np.ones([880, 880, 3], dtype=np.uint8) * 255   # initialize the whole RGB-Array with (255, 255, 255)

canvas[flt_m<50] = (100, 150, 200)      # set all values where flt_m is <50 to (100, 150, 200)
```

*However, if you do have negative values in `flt_m`, you can still add*

```
canvas[flt_m<0] = (0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: You should probably set `dtype=np.uint8` on `np.ones()` to avoid generating a float64 type.

Comment: setting `dtype=np.uint8` really helped, now the execution time is down by 2 secs.

Comment: @Steven97102 That seems very slow for 880x880. Are you using a Raspberry Pi or something similar?

Comment: Hmm I’m actually running on a intel i5, don’t know why it’s so slow

Answer (score 5):

You already have a good solution with @SpghttCd 's answer, but your write times seem very slow, so I had a think about an alternative solution...

As you only have 2-3 colours in your image, you could maybe write a palettised image (which will support up to 256 colours) and that should take less memory, less processing and less disk space. Rather than storing 3 bytes (1 for Red, 1 for Green and 1 for Blue) for each pixel, it stores a single byte at each pixel and that byte is an index into a 256 colour RGB lookup table or palette.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Generate synthetic image of same size with random numbers under 256
flt_im = np.random.randint(0,256,(880,880), dtype=np.uint8)

# Make numpy array into image without allocating any more memory
p = Image.fromarray(flt_im, mode='L')

# Create a palette with 256 colours - first 50 are your blueish colour, rest are white
palette = 50*[100,150,200] +  206*[255,255,255]

# Put palette into image and save
p.putpalette(palette)
p.save('result.png')
```

Obviously I can't check performance on your machine, but if I compare my palettised version with SpghttCd's version I get a massive 50x speed difference:

```
def SpghttCd(flt_im):
    canvas = np.ones([880, 880, 3], dtype=np.uint8) * 255

    canvas[flt_im<50] = (100, 150, 200)
    imageio.imwrite('SpghttCd.png', canvas)


def me(flt_im):
    # Make numpy array into image without allocating any more memory
    p = Image.fromarray(flt_im, mode='L')

    # Create a palette with 256 colours - first 50 are your blueish colour, rest are white
    palette = 50*[100,150,200] +  206*[255,255,255]

    # Put palette into image and save
    p.putpalette(palette)
    p.save('result.png')

# Generate random data to test with - same for both
flt_im = np.random.randint(0,256,(880,880), dtype=np.uint8)

%timeit me(flt_im)
In [34]: %timeit me(flt_im)                                                                         
34.1 ms ± 1.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [37]: %timeit SpghttCd(flt_im)                                                                   
1.68 s ± 7.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I note that changing from a PNG to a GIF (which is just as capable for this type of thing) results in a further 7x improvement in speed, i.e. 5ms instead of 34ms.

Comment: This is amazing!